# Referenced Assembly is missing in XAP

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application. I have defined Resource assembly. I referred the same into my app. at runtime, I am getting exception that Resource Assembly is not found. I unzipped xap and I found that assembly is missing in XAP. I am not sure why? Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that your resources are "Embedded" not only referenced, that is checked in the properties window in Visual Studio